# ng-include not working after back button

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with ng-include directive declared like this

```
 <div name="mainContent" data-ng-include="mainContentTemplateUrl">
 </div>
```

In the controller for the page I subscribe to "MainContentChangeRequested" event that gets raised from actions menu. Handler then figures out what template to load and changes the value of mainContentTemplateUrl like this

```
function inDefaultCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $location, $timeout, insuredProfileSvc) {

        $scope.title = controllerId;

        $scope.myid = generateQuickGuid();

        $scope.subscribe('InsuredUpdated', controllerId, function (insured) { $scope.insured = insured; });

        activate();

function activate() {
           $scope.subscribe("MainContentChangeRequested", controllerId, function (payload) { loadMainContent(payload.routeName); });

            $scope.$on("$routeUpdate", function (event) {
                console.log("routeUpdate");
            });

            load();
     }

     function loadMainContent(routeName) {
           $scope.mainContentTemplateUrl = $scope.getTemplateUrl(routeName);
           $location.search('view', routeName).replace();
     }

    function generateQuickGuid() {
                return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) +
                    Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    }
```

}
This all works fine, I am able to swap in views without isues, but, if I click back button, and then come back to page again, nothing works, I am not able to swap in views any more. I debugged code, and all code gets executed, the maintContentTemplateUrl gets changed and but it looks like ng-include does not do anything. Any ideas?

1. Update 1: If I do refresh, then everything works again.
2. Update 2: I debugged angular code and it does not call into ngIncludeFillContentDirective at all, after back button.
3. Update 3: So, I had an idea to see if the scope that is receiving update is the same as the one that is attached to the view after back button, and it is not. I created a "myid" attribute on the scope, and when user navigates back to the page, scope that is displayed in the view is not the same as the one that is subscribing to the "MainContentChangeRequested" event. Also $scope.$parent.$$destroyed is set to true. So, I have a reference to a scope, whose parent has been destroyed. Looks like it might be an issue with custom "subscribe" function, leaving a reference to a scope that has been destroyed I guess by angular.

Comment: Mmm... let's try a hack just to know if the problem comes from there, place in top of your HTML a div with the following class ".rootcontainer", add in your controller the following code $timeout(function() {
  $('.rootcontainer').trigger('resize');
}, 100); (just force a redraw).

Comment: @Braulio: Thanks Braulio, but that does not seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, finally figured it out. This was classical example of memory leak. We have a notification service, that one can send messages from controller to controller, or from service to service, without relying on the angular's $scope $emit/$broadcast/$on. And it works pretty well, but in this case, since we navigate away from the page, and we attached subscribers to the $scope, we get into situation where angular has "destroyed" the scope, but since we have reference through subscriber to a $scope, it is still in memory, and we get memory leak. This is because, unlike angular, this service has no mechanism to remove message subscribes when navigation happens. Hint that something like that is happening was a $$desrtoyed flag on the $parent of the $scope.

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, for me it was the fact that I had forgot i attached an ng-show to the div which i no longer needed.  After removing it the behavior went away.  But your response still helped put me on the trail.